# Execute sp_update_jobstep to change SQL Agent job step type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, jobs

As I was going to deploy a change to our Ola Hallengren indexing scripts, I noticed on some SQL Servers we have indexing job running as an "Operating System (CmdExec)" step instead of being called as a "Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)" step.

I'm using CMS to deploy this using `sp_update_jobstep` and I'm wanting everything as "Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)".

It doesn't appear that there's a way to change the step ([unless I'm getting the terminology confused in this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-jobstep-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

```
use msdb
go

exec sp_update_jobstep @job_name = N'IndexOptimize_USER_DATABASES', 
                       @step_id = 1, 
                       @command = N'EXECUTE [dbo].[IndexOptimize], @Databases = ''USER_DATABASES'', @LogToTable = ''Y'', @LockTimeOut = 300'
```

Is there a way to change the step type?

Comment: Just as an FYI, there's a reason why Ola had them as CmdExec. Prior to 2012, Agent terminated TSQL steps on errors hence using CmdExec instead of TSQL.

Comment: Good to know. I'm guessing we should be OK since we're a SQL 2016 shop. Not sure how one server has CmdExec and the others have TSQL. This particular instance must've not gotten his newest version.

Comment: Yes, earlier versions of his scripts did indeed use CmdExec, so that is a likely cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@subsystem=N'TSQL'` parameter of the `sp_update_jobstep` to alter the Step-Type.  Refer to [sp_add_jobstep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-jobstep-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for a list of valid subsystem values.

Example:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep @job_name = N'test'
    ,@step_id = 1
    ,@subsystem = N'TSQL'
    ,@command = N'EXECUTE [dbo].[IndexOptimize], @Databases = ''USER_DATABASES'', @LogToTable = ''Y'', @LockTimeOut = 300'
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, this did the trick

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if you want to script out a change for Agent jobs & you're not sure how - you can use the 
 <kbd>⎎ Script ▾</kbd> button in the GUI to script out all the changes you've staged in the current session.

For example, if I want to change that same job `IndexOptimize_USER_DATABASES` to no longer log to table, I'd follow something like the below screencapped steps...

[image: stage the change in the jobstep text box and press "ok"]

[image: select the location to export your script]

...which would give me a new query window with the following text.

```sql
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep @job_id=N'cbbf1dc7-d128-499e-91d3-4df88ada2e5f', @step_id=1 , 
        @command=N'EXECUTE [dbo].[IndexOptimize]
@Databases = ''USER_DATABASES'',
@LogToTable = ''N'''
GO
```